# How can I make sure my PHP code is compatible with a newer version

Tags: php, ide, compatibility, upgrade

I have a bunch of PHP 5.6 code that I would like to get up to 7.2. My biggest concern was the change that causes an error when you call a function without enough parameters.  Previously, this was a warning. This is the change I know for a fact affects me, but others may as well.  So what I did is I put together a small sample file and started opening it in various IDEs to see if any of them would tell me that it is not valid 7.2. So far I am 0 for 3.

Apparently this is a run time error, so simply running the file or running it with -l doesn't work.  So how can I make sure my code is acceptable for PHP 7.2 without manually going through every file?

Comment: 1. Install php 7 in a test environment (e.g. your local computer). 2. Test your code using that version. 3. Fix any problems until everything works.

Comment: The problem is by the time I finish that, PHP 200 will be released.

Comment: Don't you have unit tests? If not, then it's a good time to add them

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough.  There is too much code to simply add unit tests. Support for php 5.6 ends in about a month. I cannot add unit tests to 15 year's worth of code in a month.

Comment: Setting up a LAMP system in a VirutalBox vm takes me about 45 minutes.... turn on all error reporting, `tail -f` your error log file(s) and test it.

Comment: Use `php -l filename.php` on all your PHP files for a quick and dirty check as a first place to start: `php -l $(find . -name "*.php")`

Comment: Unfortunately -l only finds syntax errors and the function-call-with-too-few-arguments is a runtime error. That is very useful information for similar problems though, so thank you for commenting.

Comment: `I guess I wasn't clear enough. There is too much code to simply add unit tests. Support for php 5.6 ends in about a month. I cannot add unit tests to 15 year's worth of code in a month.` time for the company to pay the technical debt.

Comment: Ha, I think the company's stance is "hold on until we can phase it (and you) out."

Answer (score 4):

Sorry about all the down voters who didn't bother leaving a reason why.  I was in your EXACT situation, and here is what I did:

I used a static code analysis tool.  I tried a few, but the first one that actually worked how I wanted to was [Phan](https://github.com/phan/phan). Installation was a pain and the documentation isn't the best, but once you figure out the syntax, it's very useful.

1. Create a list of php files you want to validate.

   cd C:\SomeDir
   dir /s /b *.php > C:\phpfiles.txt
2. Run phan with that list as an argument.

   vendor\bin\phan -f C:\phpfiles.txt > C:\output.txt
3. If you only want certain results, for example if you only want PhanParamTooFew results, use findstr:

   findstr /c:"PhanParamTooFew " C:\output.txt > C:\filteredoutput.txt

There are config settings to do that third bit, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Did you just answer your own question thinking it was asked by someone else? 

Comment: Haha the "exact" was capital for a reason.  I continued seeking answers after posting and this is what I came up with. I hope to help future travelers.